# How to set default value for route parameter based on configured value?

Tags: 8, routes

I have a route with optional parameter that has some default value:

```
# file @hello.routing.yml
hello.sayHi:
  path: '/hello/{name}'
  defaults: 
    _title: 'Say Hi'
    _content: 'Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback::sayHiAction'
    name: 'there'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

I'd like to make `there` value for `{name}` parameter configurable. Let's assume that this default value for `{name}` is available in simple config variable.

Comment: Have you tried adding a default value to the controller method  (sayHiAction)?

Comment: Remove the name form route and use it in controller. why are you trying to complicate things for yourself? :D

Comment: @IvanJaros because I want to go by the book, be consistent and maybe use parameter upcasting?

Comment: Either you haven't explained what you want correctly, or I didn't understood what you want or you don't understand what "I want to go by the book" means :D .. as I'm reading the answer from cilefen I think you might want to have a look at \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase

Comment: OK, so symfony allows you to use config parameter values in yaml file by referencing them with a % sign. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782406 I'm looking for similar behavior that will work for Drupal's simple config. BTW it would be awesome if we could use simple config variables in yaml files like we can with symfonys native config parameters. "By the book" I mean the best practice approach, like with symfonys service: you don't use default value in a service constructor but instead you inject the value in your service definition.

Comment: Besides I can't use hard coded value like suggested by @Eyal - this "default" value needs to be configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement a [route alter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643). In the alter code, extract the setting and set the value on the route definition.

Comment: This looks promissing. I'll give it a shoot. I'd be happy to accept your answer, but can you update it with code example just for sake of stackexchange rules?

Comment: No. SE has their rules and I have mine. It is well-documented at the link.

Answer (score 1):

Implement two routes one with an argument and the second without.

### hello.routing.yml

```
hello.sayHi:
  path: '/hello/{name}'
  defaults: 
    _title: 'Say Hi'
    _content: 'Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback::sayHiAction'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
hello.sayHi.default:
  path: '/hello'
  defaults: 
    _title: 'Say Hi'
    _content: 'Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback::sayHiAction'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

### hello.config.yml

```
default_name: there
```

### hello.services.yml

```
hello.config:
  factory: ['@config.factory', get]
  class: Drupal\Core\Config\Config
  arguments: ['hello.config']
```

### Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback

```
protected $configuration;

public function __constructor(Config $configuration) {
  $this->configuration = $configuration;
}

public static function create(Container $container) {
  return new static($container->get('hello.config'));
}

public function sayHiAction($name = NULL) {
  $name = is_null($name) ? $this->configuration->get('default_name') : $name;
  return [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => 'Hi {name}',
    '#context' => [
      'name' => $name
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes

Optional parameters

Parameters on routes can be omitted when a default value for the parameter is supplied. Imagine you have a form controller that allows people to report different issues (e.g. bug reports, feature requests and support requests), and if the type is omitted it should default to 'support request'. Supply the default value for the optional parameter in the "defaults" section:

```
issue.report_form:
  path: '/report/{issue_type}'
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\issue\Controller\IssueController::report'
    issue_type: 'support-request'
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'report issue'
```